# Number format with Amcharts Javascript

Tags: amcharts

Amchart give me amazing graphics into HTML but...

How to format the number axis? 
Currently it shows me 65,000 and I need value like 65000. No commas!

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I solved the problem!

Into `AmCharts.ready(function(){` put

```
chart.numberFormatter = {
  precision:-1,decimalSeparator:",",thousandsSeparator:""
};
```

All Number Format happens there!

---

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
        [...]
        "numberFormatter": {
            "precision": -1,
            "decimalSeparator": ",",
            "thousandsSeparator": ""
        }
    });
```

Comment: Seems to still work for AmCharts v3 although it is not included in the documentation

Comment: @geoand it is now: https://docs.amcharts.com/javascriptcharts/AmChart#numberFormatter

Answer (score 2):

If you need to format definite number:

```
var formatted = AmCharts.formatNumber(number, 
{
     precision: chart.precision,
     decimalSeparator: chart.decimalSeparator,
     thousandsSeparator: chart.thousandsSeparator
}, 2);
```

> formatNumber(number, formatter, zeroCount)
>
> Returns string formatter with the provided settings. Formatter is an
>   object with precision, decimalSeparator and thousandsSeparator
>   defined, like: {precision: 2, decimalSeparator: '.',
>   thousandsSeparator: ','}; If you don't need to adjust precision set it
>   to -1. zeroCount defines how many zeros should be added after comma
>   (useful when formatting currencies).

Comment: Hi @Zvezdochka, where to use **formatted**, to reflect the changes?

Answer (score 1):

Put this, it will remove, from thousands (refer [docs](http://docs.amcharts.com/2/javascriptcharts/AmChart))

```
"numberFormatter": {precision:-1, decimalSeparator:',', thousandsSeparator:''},
```